# Get-ADComputers doesnt work on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to run a script on a PC with Windows Server 2012 R2, but it stops at `Get-ADComputer`.

It says it's not a Cmdlet, but the same script works fine on my Windows 10.

Somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: Improved formatting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import ActiveDirectory module?

```
Import-Module activedirectory
```

Comment: I just imported it and now the complete script doesn't run at all. It doesn't seem to realize that it's even code... No errors, just my script as a text

Comment: What is the execution policy setting?

Run Get-ExecutionPolicy

Could you post a bit of a code here so we can check?

Comment: it suddenly worked after 20 minutes. Don't know why though, thanks :-)